# Authentication using existing websites in Android chat apps

Tags: android, firebase, chat

I want to create a chat app for Android but instead of registering with an email or phone number I would like users to sign in with their account on an already existing website account. For example, If I'm creating a chat app specifically for movies, I would make the authentication through their IMDB account. Is there any way to do this? Usually I work with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but using firebase is meaningless in this scenario. Firebase is a "BaaS" (back-end as a service) which you generally use to store data or send notifications. In your example, you want to connect your users with their IMDB account so you already know the back-end you should use. To connect the users with a system you should read their API docs and send POST/GET requests which generally contains a username, a password, and an API key. After that depending on the service, you should get the JSON/XML response from the server, and let the user continue if the response code is 200.(SUCCESS). To make the call take a look at

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

To test this with an API, take a look at themoviedb which is free to use.

https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Comment: If you want to provide "sign in with your IMDB/Facebook/GitHub/SO account" functionality, it is common to use something like OAuth2 instead of asking users for their credentials. Your app should not be storing/handling a user's credentials for somebody else's service.

Comment: Yours is a better approach. My answer was aimed to provide a starting point since the person who asked the question has no idea where to begin.

Comment: I wasn't trying to contradict you :) I agree that learning how to use [REST](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest) (or other web-APIs) should come first. Though I would suggest to use something like [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) instead of [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection), especially for a beginner. I just think that mentioning [OAuth 2](https://oauth.net/2/) is fairly important in the context of this question ("once you know the basics, here's how to do it properly").

Comment: I think I got it, so in that case I won't even need a database of users right? It's all going to be just IMDB accounts?

Comment: For your purposes you do not need a database. Think about it. You want to let users login with their imdb account. Their imdb account's credentials are stored in imdb and they will not share their user's credentials with you. That's exactly why you need to send a request to a server and ask if this username and password is valid. Still this is not a real life solution as you should not know their pw while sending request. You DO need a database if you decide to register users and do not accept third party authentication for your own application to check their credentials when they login later.

Comment: Since this solution is not applicable for authenticating a user in real life, you should next learn about OAuth2 like Markus said. But this approach is valid and used for nearly everything else. For example you want to search for a list of movies with genre=drama, then you can send a request about it using the approach I suggested in the answer. I would suggest you to get familiar with sending requests/getting responses before writing your application. By the way after authenticating users in you should still use database to retrieve chat history. You can also check XMPP protocol for chat app

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly broad which makes it difficult to answer in any detail.

In any case, you want to authenticate your users so you know who-is-who. This means your users need to provide some form of credentials. You don't want users to create a new account, instead they should be able to use one of their existing accounts (e.g. IMDb) to authenticate themselves.

**How to authenticate?**

As Sam says, to allow a user to sign in with IMDb you need to be able to talk to IMDb's servers first. This means you need some form of API, that allows you to send HTTP requests to IMDb's servers.

As far as I can see, IMDb doesn't offer much in terms of a public API or any way to authenticate a user with their IMDb account.

You may want to look into [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) instead. It already supports a number of services (Google, Facebook, Twitter, GitHub) and takes care of all the low level details. You want to build a chat app, not an identity service after all.

**Do I still need my own database and user accounts?**

Yes

Once a user is authenticated you may want to store some data about them (name, email, ...). The service used to authenticate a user may or may not provide you with this information. Users also may not want to share all of those details with your app. On top of that you probably want to be able to link a user's chat history with their account. This means you need to store this information somewhere.

**What else?**

All of this just takes care of authentication. You still need to provide the necessary infrastructure for users to actually be able to talk to one another. This means you need your own server that the app can use to route messages to other users. You could probably use some other Firebase services for this (e.g. [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/)).